# How to create a predicate where value contains sequence of characters like Xcode filtering

Tags: objective-c, regex, cocoa, predicate, nsregularexpression

I want to implement Xcode function filtering with predicate. If you filter the function names in Xcode, by "myFunc" it will look for that sequence of characters not the exact string.

Example:

momsYellowFunCar
**m**     **Y**   **FunC**

Would I have to use MATCHES and provide a regex some how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using NSRegularExpression which is built-in on 10.7+ and iOS 4.0+. Something like the following:

```
NSArray *stringsToSearch = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"mYFunC", @"momsYellowFunCar", @"Hello World!", nil];
NSString *searchString = @"mYFunC";
NSMutableString *regexPattern = [NSMutableString string];
for (NSUInteger i=0; i < [searchString length]; i++) {
    NSString *character = [searchString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
    [regexPattern appendFormat:@"%@.*", character];
}
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexPattern
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators
                                                                         error:&error];
if (!regex) {
    NSLog(@"Couldn't create regex: %@", error);
    return;
}

NSMutableArray *matchedStrings = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *string in stringsToSearch) {
    if ([regex numberOfMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])] > 0) {
        [matchedStrings addObject:string];
    }
}

NSLog(@"Matched strings: %@", matchedStrings); // mYFunC and momsYellowFunCar, but not Hello World!
```

If you have to use an NSPredicate, you can use a variation of this code with `-[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:]`.

Comment: thanks. I wasn't expecting all the code. It's much appreciated.